# "This browser does not support WebAssembly." - in Chrome

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

We have created a Blazor (wasm) application, and have installed sentry so we know of any issues.

The one we have at the moment is "This browser does not support WebAssembly." - however the are using Chrome v83.0.4103 - which is supported (and I've tested on the specific version as well).

Is there something  that might be blocking Web Aseembly on supported browsers at all?

Comment: There is a page for that. https://github.com/stevespringett/disable-webassembly

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I have this problem in one specific Chrome profile